# pass < or > operator into function as parameter?

Tags: actionscript-3, parameters, operators

Inside my function there is an `if()` statement like this:

```
if(passedValue < staticValue)
```

But I need to be able to pass a parameter dictating whether the if expression is like above or is:

```
if(passedValue > staticValue)
```

But I cant really pass `<` or `>` operator in has a parameter, so I was wondering what is the best way to do this?

Also if the language I am using matters its ActionScript 3.0

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of passing an operator, which is impossible in AS3, why not pass a custom comparison function?

```
function actualFunction(passedValue:Number, compareFunction:Function) {
    /* ... */

    if(compareFunction(passedValue, staticValue)) {
        /* ... Do something ... */
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Then to use it:

```
actualFunction(6, function(x:Number, y:Number) {
     return x > y;
});
```

or:

```
actualFunction(6, function(x:Number, y:Number) {
     return x < y;
});
```

Comment: Good solution. Alternatively, if the author wanted to pass the operator as a string, they could use it as a lookup to retrieve the correct function (from a dictionary, or similar). It would require more setup, optionally simplified with a factory, but would result in cleaner code. (ie: not creating a dynamic function each place the call is made)

Comment: "(ie: not creating a dynamic function each place the call is made)" - Flash optimizes the function to be static, so there's no performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the function take a `bool` as an argument and perform the comparison directly when calling the function?

```
ExampleFunction(arg1, (passedValue > staticValue))
```

Comment: What if the callee has no access to staticValue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Actionscript, but can't you make a variable called:

bool greaterThan = true;

and if its true, do >, if its false do < ?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you can't pass operators. You can pass a variable indicating which operator to use though.

```
lessThan = true;
func(passedValue, lessThan);
```