# Passing operator to setInterval() actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I would like assign `setInterval()` to pass an operator as an argument by following the Answer of LiraNuna

```
function actualFunction(passedValue:Number, compareFunction:Function) {
    /* ... */

    if(compareFunction(passedValue, staticValue)) {
        /* ... Do something ... */
    }

    /* ... */
}

actualFunction(6, function(x:Number, y:Number) {
     return x > y;
});
```

from this link [pass < or > operator into function as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067360/pass-or-operator-into-function-as-parameter)

But I don't seem to know how to do it since only the function name is called when initiating `setInterva()`.

Typical initiation:

```
function actualFunction(passedValue:Number, compareFunction:Function) {
    /* ... */

    if(compareFunction(passedValue, staticValue)) {
        /* ... Do something ... */
    }

    /* ... */
}
setInterval(actualFunction,10)
```

Now, I want to assign

```
actualFunction(6, function(x:Number, y:Number) {
     return x > y;
});
```

within `setInterval()`, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (not tested) :

```
setInterval(actualFunction, 10, 6, function(x:Number, y:Number){return x > y});
```

Read this for more information : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval()

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do we include the 'return x > y', because in other case, we would also be calling the 'setInterval()' with, 'return x < y'?

Comment: I've edited my answer please test and see if it works. Try to create separate methods for comparison and not pass them as in line methods if you are going to call this code many times.

Comment: i got the whole code working but it requires two functions, with only the difference is x >y and x < y. i will try this and see if it works :)

Comment: In that case would recommend create two separate methods first, one to return x>y and the other for x<y. Pass those functions as a parameter then. Do let me know if it helps, thanks

Comment: Great :) glad I could help :)